# PHP - Unwanted break line in the input when accessing page from windows

Tags: php, laravel, encoding

I have a text that I want to put it in the textarea, submit the form and process it. I get the content of this textarea as usual Laravel `$request->fieldName`. The problem is when I access the page from Unix OS and  submit the form, it is ok but when I fill textarea the same text and send it through windows, some break line randomly added between lines of it.
I read about break line encoding in the windows and Unix OS and as it is said I tried:

```
$content = preg_replace('#\r\n?#', "\n", $content);
```

but it doesn't work. Does anybody has an idea about what's wrong?

Comment: Some browsers will send `<br>` along with the line breaks when submitting a form with fields of type textarea. Perhaps that's what you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Try PHP_EOL:

```
str_replace(PHP_EOL,"\n",$content); // Or to remove break line str_replace(PHP_EOL,'',$content);
```